# Django - add parameter to url

Tags: django

I have an url like `/documents/search?q=searchterm`. On that page, I have an dropdown box where another searchterm can be added. That box has an onchange event and reloads the page:

```
<form><select name="w" class="form-control" onchange="this.form.submit();">
```

When the onchange event fires, the page is reloaded and the `w` parameter is added to the url, but the `q` parameter is lost. How can I tell my form, that on reload all the existing parameters are kept?

Comment: When you reload the page, you point to a view. In that view I guess you have something like: `return reverse('url_name')`. You could get the `q` param in your view and add like this: `return '%s?q=%s' % (reverse('url_name'), q_param_got_from_request)`

Comment: Just a suggestion, you can try URI.js https://github.com/medialize/URI.js/. You can manipulate your url as much as you like(The README in their project says everything). It might be overkill for your current case, but you might have more `GET` parameters to handle in other cases. Who knows :).

Answer (score 0):

You need to include any other parameters in the form as hidden inputs:

```
<form>
    <select name="w" class="form-control" onchange="this.form.submit();">
    <input type="hidden" name="q" value="{{ search_term }}">
</form>
```

You need to make sure that `search_term` (obtained from the GET parameters) is in the context being passed to the template.

If possible you should consider using Django's [Forms API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/api/) to manage the form data.